# how use a post Response to call a new Post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap-4

I'm making an API with nodeJS as a back-end of my front-end web application with Bootstrap.
Started to learn front-end yesterday and almost don't know what to do.

Now, I almost fixed all the bugs but can't find a way to use my response from the post that I send.

here is my back-end route:

```
    app.post('/move/data', function (req, res) {

        let movement = req.body;
        console.log(movement);

        if (validateMove(movement).status != 200) {
            console.log(movement)
            res.send(validateMove(movement).message);
        }
        position = (Number(movement.holeSize) * 10) - 25;
        console.log(position);

        res.sendStatus(validateMove(movement).status) // No Front, chamar o up
    });
```

and here the script in front end

```
function sendData() {

    console.log('start')
    // test to check transition
    // document.getElementById('worm').style.top = "300px";

    const dataForm = new FormData(document.getElementById("dataForm"));

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/move/data', {
        method: 'post',
        body: dataForm
    }).then(function (respose) {
        return respose.text();
    }).then(function (text) {
        console.log(text);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}

function moveUp(position) {

}

function moveDown(position) {

    moveUp(position);
}
```

What I need to do is make a worm goes up and down in a hole until it gets free.
I want to make this by calling the back-end API, but don't need how make this calls after receive my response from post.

Anyone can help me with some tip?

I Also want to change the property "heigth" from my "hole" image using JS

Comment: Why did you change the code in the question? Now the answer doesn't make sense in the new context.

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning frontend, then you've stumbled on one of the advanced parts already, which is making XHR requests and dealing with asynchronous code.

I'd suggest that you don't use the older `XMLHttpRequest` interface in favor of the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). It's a simpler and more powerful API that does the same but with an easier syntax.

A fetch request returns a `Promise` which is part of the asynchronous code. You can wait for the request to finish by using the [`async / await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax. It makes your code *almost* look like synchronous code but with extra powers.

```
/**
 * Since you are dealing here with promises you can use
 * the async / await syntax.
 */
async function sendData() {
  console.log('start')
  // test to check transition
  // document.getElementById('worm').style.top = "300px";

  const FD = new FormData(form);
  let response;

  try {
    // Fetch the resource and wait for the response to come in
    // before continuing in the sendData function.
    console.log('Fetching');
    response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/move/data', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: FD
    });
  } catch (error) {
    alert('Oops! algo deu errado');
  }

  // At this point the response has been successful and
  // we can parse the body of the response to a string.
  console.log('Fetch successful. Parsing to text.');
  const text = await response.text();

  console.log('Text parsed', text);
  // Now you can use the response that is in the 
  // text variable in the rest of your code.

  // Maybe parse the text to a number for your position?
  const position = Number(text);
  let size = position + 'px'
  console.log('The size is', size);
  document.getElementById('hole').style.height = size;

  moveUp(position);
}
```

Comment: wow, the Try-Catch helps a lot.
I will make some tests here. But I Beliave that it would work.
Thanks a lot

Comment: it works! =) I just can't change the heitght of my image using a variable "size" (position + px)

Comment: `document.getElementById('hole').style.height` is the correct setter for the height. But if it fails it's either that the `size` variable isn't a valid value as a height. Or there is some CSS with `!important` statements in play that overwrite the height.

Comment: The way you show to use try-catch saves me. Now I need to find a way to assing a new value to a CSS style using a variable

something like "x =- 2" in Java (that will makes x = x - 2)

document.getElementById('worm').style.top = (Don't know how)

Thanks for your help


Sorry, posted a aswer